# Poland invitation letter

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, poland, invitation-letters

I'm an Indian.I have a cousin who is a student in Poland. He told me that he will send me an invitation letter so that I can pretty easily get a visit visa to Poland.

Can students send invitation letters? If yes where should he submit the application? In voivoid office in Poland or Polish Embassy in India? How long will the whole process take?

Comment: An invitation letter will not, by itself, make it "pretty easy" to get a Schengen visa. It can help you show that (a) your purpose of the visit is what you say it is (if you say that your purpose is to visit your friend), and (b) that you have a place to sleep (if you plan to stay at your friend's home). All of the other visa conditions -- in particular convincing the consular officer that you have a reason to go back to your home country after the trip rather than immigrate illegally -- are still for you to establish, and an invitation letter is not going to make _that_ any easier.

Answer (score 2):

> Can students send invitation letters?

Yes.

> If yes where should he submit the application?

To you, for inclusion with the rest of the paperwork for your application.

> In voivoid office in Poland or Polish Embassy in India?

Not applicable (see above).

> How long will the whole process take?

Depends on where the application is made and other factors such as the complexity and completeness of the application.

For [New Delhi](http://www.newdelhi.mfa.gov.pl/en/consular_information/visa_information/):

> 4. The visa processing time.
>
> According to the Schengen Visa Code the processing time can take up to
>   14 working days.
>
> In some exceptional cases the processing time can be prolonged up to
>   30 days.